# Home router website redirect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I need that anyone connected to my home's wifi and trying to access Facebook, be redirected to a particular website.

I don't know anything about networking and I have a ZTE ZXHN H108N router, can some one please help me to do this? in a really simple way?

If there is a software that does it, I would appreciate it. Or can I do it from my router setting which I can access from 192.168.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do what you are wanting to with this router.  You would need to install another device behind it - something which can run Dd-WRT or similar.

Comment: any suggestion on a device ?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here, but there is a list of devices at http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices  - Note that getting dd-wrt on it is only the first step - once you have this you will need to work out how to configure it to do what you want - if its just for 1 site and low security, you probably would modify DNSMasq to modify the DNS, otherwise you are looking at some kind of proxy setup.